# Why does physisorption change to chemisorption at high temperatures?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, adsorption

I read in my textbook:

> In certain cases, physisorption changes to chemisorption as temperature is increased.

Could anyone explain why it is so? I know the basics of both physisorption and chemisorption, but I am unable to relate them to this statement.

Comment: Presumably your book assumes that there is a larger activation barrier for chemisorption than physisorption (normally the case) and that that cannot be crossed at a low temperature, so here physisorption is favoured.